# Combining two conflicting checkbox jQuery scripts

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use two jQuery scripts that seem to be conflicting with each other. One will not work while the other is included. I am fairly new to jQuery so I have found these scripts online and wish to use them both at the same time.

The first script turns a button into a checkbox and the second script dynamically adds the checkbox value to a list when selected (and removes when de-selected).

I would really appreciate if someone could explain where I am going wrong and how to make both scripts work.

Also on another note to develop the second script, is it possible to add an "X" to the end of each list entry so the user can click this to remove the value from the list and also de-select the checkbox?

Any help is much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/73zounsc/

HTML:

```
<form class="container" action="#" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h3>Most Popular</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-block btn-outline-dark">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="x" id="x" value="x" autocomplete="off">x
</label>
<label class="btn btn-block btn-outline-dark">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="y" id="y" value="y" autocomplete="off">y
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-block btn-outline-dark">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="z" id="z" value="z" autocomplete="off">z
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="card shadow-sm">
<div class="card-body">
<h3 class="card-title">Itinerary</h3>
<!-- JQUERY ACTIONS HERE -->
<div id="list">
<ul>

</ul>
<!-- JQUERY ACTIONS HERE -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('[data-toggle="buttons"] .btn').on('click', function () {
        //toggle style
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        // toggle checkbox
        var $chk = $(this).find('[type=checkbox]');
        $chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));

        return false;
    });

    $('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('<li />').appendTo('#list ul').text($(this).val());
        }
        else {
            $('#list li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way should be to combine the two functions into one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="buttons"] .btn').on('click', function () {
        //toggle style
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        // toggle checkbox
        var $chk = $(this).find('[type=checkbox]');
        $chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));

        if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
            $('<li />').appendTo('#list ul').text($chk.val());
        }
        else {
            $('#list li:contains('+$chk.val()+')').remove();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

As for adding a remove button, you'd have to append another HTML element with a remove function on its click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="buttons"] .btn').on('click', function () {
        //toggle style
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        // toggle checkbox
        var $chk = $(this).find('[type=checkbox]');
        $chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));

        if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
            var li = $('<li></li>').text($chk.val());

            //Create removal button
            li.append($('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RemoveLI(\''+$chk.val()+'\')">X</i>'))

            li.appendTo('#list ul');
        }
        else {
            $('#list li:contains('+$chk.val()+')').remove();
        }

        return false;
    });
});


function RemoveLI(val) {
    $('#list li:contains('+val+')').remove();

    //Remove check & active class
    var $chk = $.find('[type=checkbox][value="'+val+'"]');
    $chk = $($chk[0]);
    $chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));

    $chk.parent().toggleClass('active')
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzwsn837/)